# Issue in Lineage OS 20 : OmxStore: omx common prefix: no nodes

Tags: android, graphics, omxplayer, openmax, lineageos

I am not able to screen record in lineage 20 and i am getting error with OpenMax component.
Omx (OpenMAX) Component Node not initiating that's why not getting "OMX" as an omx common prefix and also not creating Component instance for video encoding.

```
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: called createOMXPlugin for Goldfish
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: useOmxCodecs 54 found prop debug.stagefright.ccodec val 0
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: useAndroidGoldfishComponentInstance 85 found prop ro.boot.qemu.hwcodec.vpxdec val 2
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: found and use kComponents[i].name OMX.android.goldfish.vp8.decoder
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: useAndroidGoldfishComponentInstance 85 found prop ro.boot.qemu.hwcodec.vpxdec val 2
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: found and use kComponents[i].name OMX.android.goldfish.vp9.decoder
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: useAndroidGoldfishComponentInstance 85 found prop ro.boot.qemu.hwcodec.avcdec val 2
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: found and use kComponents[i].name OMX.android.goldfish.h264.decoder
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: enumerate OMX.android.goldfish.vp8.decoder component
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: enumerate OMX.android.goldfish.vp9.decoder component
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: enumerate OMX.android.goldfish.h264.decoder component
I SoftOMXPlugin: createOMXPlugin
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml...
I servicemanager: Found android.hardware.radio.data.IRadioData/slot1 in device VINTF manifest.
I servicemanager: Found android.hardware.radio.messaging.IRadioMessaging/slot1 in device VINTF manifest.
I servicemanager: Found android.hardware.radio.modem.IRadioModem/slot1 in device VINTF manifest.
I servicemanager: Found android.hardware.radio.network.IRadioNetwork/slot1 in device VINTF manifest.
I servicemanager: Found android.hardware.radio.sim.IRadioSim/slot1 in device VINTF manifest.
I servicemanager: Found android.hardware.radio.voice.IRadioVoice/slot1 in device VINTF manifest.
I servicemanager: Found android.hardware.radio.config.IRadioConfig/default in device VINTF manifest.
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 85 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 88 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 91 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 95 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 98 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 101 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 104 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_google_audio.xml...
I bt_vhci_forwarder: ignore 0xff packet
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_google_telephony.xml...
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_google_video.xml...
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_performance.xml...
I MediaCodecsXmlParser: Did not find media_codecs_shaping.xml in search path
I HidlServiceManagement: Registered android.hardware.media.omx@1.0::IOmx/default
I HidlServiceManagement: Removing namespace from process name android.hardware.media.omx@1.0-service to omx@1.0-service.
I android.hardware.media.omx@1.0-service: IOmx HAL service created.
I OmxStore: omx common prefix: no nodes
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml...
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 85 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 88 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 91 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 95 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 98 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 101 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 104 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_google_audio.xml...
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_google_telephony.xml...
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_google_video.xml...
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_performance.xml...
I MediaCodecsXmlParser: Did not find media_codecs_shaping.xml in search path
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.aac.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.amrnb.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.amrwb.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.flac.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.g711.alaw.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.g711.mlaw.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.gsm.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.mp3.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.opus.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.raw.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.aac.encoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.amrnb.encoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.amrwb.encoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.flac.encoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.android.goldfish.h264.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.h264.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.h263.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.hevc.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.mpeg4.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.android.goldfish.vp8.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.vp8.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.android.goldfish.vp9.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.vp9.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.h264.encoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.h263.encoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.mpeg4.encoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.vp8.encoder] not found in IOmx
```

I am debugging and checking but not found proper solution.

Comment: Also posted on Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/254084/44325